# Changing voice characteristics so it sounds like someone else voice

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, audio, pitch, voice

I have a recording of speech, and I want to manipulate the voice, so a listener
will perceive the manipulated voice and the original one as belonging to two 
different people. The manipulated voice should sound very natural, not computer-generated.

Just to clarify, the manipulated voice does not have to be modeled after the voice of someone; I'm not asking about mimicking a voice, as discussed [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7833/how-to-mimic-copy-fake-someones-voice).

I have already used the [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/) library for pitch shifting, and it produces very nice results, but I want to change not only the pitch.

I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3M7qAHPw5qQ) impressive video of a software called Voice Sculptor (couldn't find the company site), which demonstrate such a manipulation.

- So I'm asking on a conceptual/algorithmic level how this can be done
- And also if you know how to achieve this with specific tools.

Last note: I'm new to DSP, so I will appreciate any explanation of why and how.

Comment: for me it seems pitch and formants manipulation

Answer (score 1):

You may use the same pitch shift technique, but a little bit modified. If, classically, in pitch shift algorithm, each frequency component changes by multiplication of its frequency on some pitch-shift coefficient *k*, you may try:

1. Changing a little bit the amplitude of each spectral component.
2. Multiply each frequency component not by *k*, but *k+v(f)*, where *v(f)* shows variation dependent on frequency *f*. Such variation must be of much smaller value than *k*. I mean *k >> v(f)*.